# Mapping two numeric columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

My data set has two numeric columns as shown below:

promo card

```
12       
12       
11       
11
```

payment card

```
33  
44  
33  
55
```

The data shows a person using a promo card with a payment card for a transaction.

In the first two rows, the promo card is same (12), but the payment has been made using two different payment cards (33 & 44), indicating it is customer no. 1 (say).

In the third row, a different promo card is used (11), but payment was made through a card already used before (33) along with a different promo card (12) - indicating that this is the same customer (customer no. 1).

The goal is to map these all such rows to a self-generated customer id - in essence indicating that all the rows belong to the same customer.

This is to be done using PostgreSQL.. Any help or suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: You say two _columns_. Do you perhaps mean _tables_? Or, columns in different tables, or the same table?

Comment: Your data shown can't really be used, because it lacks any sort of an `ID` column which might be used to related the data to a given person/customer.

Comment: Also: there is no such thing as "the first two rows" in a relational database. You need to have some kind of column where you can define a sort order (to be used by an `order by`)

Comment: I think there's table with the two columns and a third with a customer id is needed. Ever time a new data set will be inserted it should be checked it has to be checked if one of these numbers has been used already. In that case the customer id of this data set has to be taken, otherwise a new has to be generated. I am not sure if this has to be for a new table or has to be for existing data as well (first could be a BEFORE INSERT TRIGGER, second might be a function to fill the id column before)

Comment: How should the id look like? I can imagine a few ways: Simply concatenation of first two cards used by a customer or a hash of it. Using a sequence to generate consecutive integer ids,... What happebs if some cards are used by several customers? (borrow promo card tl friends, for example) In your use case all these customers get the same id. And if they use a family credit card the range could be never ending. Is your idea really a good one?

Comment: S-Man's objections are good. If the mapping, however, is really as simple as you think, then you can use a recursive query. Take one transaction record per `promocard_id`. For each find all other records with the same `paymentcard_id`. For each of these find all other records with the same `promocard_id`. For each of these find all other records with the same `paymentcard_id`. Etc. In this process you'll get all  `paymentcard_id` per `promocard_id`. For each `promocard_id` now take the minimum `paymentcard_id`. This is your "customer ID".

Comment: Using a programming language may be easier. For PostgreSQL you can use their PL/pgSQL. Start with two empty tables customer_promocard and customer_paymentcard. Pick a transaction record. Look up promo card and payment card in the tables. If not in there, create a customer ID and insert the cards. Then take the next transaction record and so on. In this loop insert or update records depending on your findings.

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer**:  I believe your idea is not well thought. Because in reality the cards always are borrowed and used by other persons. Think about a person who borrows his promo card to his friend. He uses the promo card with his credit card. Now the credit card is used by the friend's wife which has the promo card of her friend. This could be a neverending story and you'll definitely track many different users.

---

[demo: db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=810f69b7cd8546f2a51aa318ac3db704)

Only for **inserting data into an empty or already filled table** you could do it this way:

Create the assumed table:

```
CREATE TABLE transactions (
    id_promo int,
    id_credit int,
    id_customer int
);
```

Create a sequence which is for counting the `id_customer`:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE seq_transaction_id_customer;
```

Create a trigger function: This function checks if there is already a customer with the same promo or credit card number. In that case the corresponding ID is given. Otherwise the `SELECT` would be `NULL` and the `COALESCE` generates a new ID with help of the `SEQUENCE`.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION set_id_customer() RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    _customer_id int;
BEGIN
    SELECT DISTINCT id_customer 
    FROM transactions 
    WHERE NEW.id_promo = id_promo OR NEW.id_credit = id_credit
    INTO _customer_id;

    NEW.id_customer = COALESCE(_customer_id, nextval('seq_transaction_id_customer'));

    RETURN NEW;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Create the trigger which calls the function every time a new data set is inserted.

```
CREATE TRIGGER transaction_id_customer
    BEFORE INSERT
    ON transactions
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE set_id_customer();
```

I recommend to add an index for `id_promo` and `id_credit` if your table as many rows. With that the performance for searching an exisiting `id_customer` would be increased significantly:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_transaction_promo
ON transaction(id_promo);

CREATE INDEX idx_transaction_credit
ON transaction(id_credit);
```

---

To update an existing table to create the customer's IDs you could use a function which loops through all data sets. In principle it should look like the trigger function.